# Dropdown is not showing after a page reloads

Tags: html, jquery, dropdown

I have three dropdowns in my page, two of them are shown perfectly while the other one is not appearing, and when looking at the element in page it gets loaded with the "style="display: none;" value even if I'm forcing it with style="display: inline;".
Here's the code:

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <div id="myBrokenDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <select class='filter' id="notWorkingOne">
      <option value=""> Select</option>
      <option value="a">a</option>
      <option value="b">b</option>
      <option value="c">c</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <!--select button-->
  <div id="select1" class="dropdown-content">
    <select class='filter' id="select1Works" data-col="1">
      <option value="a">a</option>
      <option value="b">b</option>
      <option value="c">c</option>

    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="select2" class="dropdown-content">
    <select class='filter' id="select2Works" data-col="5">
      <option value=""> Select</option>
      <option value="a">a</option>
      <option value="b">b</option>
      <option value="c">c</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, in jquery I can hide/Show the two dropdowns with the following code:

```js
$('#select1Works').hide();
$('#select2Works').hide();
$('#notWorkingOne').hide();
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type='radio']").on('change', function() {
    $("#select1Works").toggle($("[name=radioButton]").index(this) === 0);
    $("#select2Works").val("").trigger("change");
    $("#select2Works").toggle($("[name=radioButton]").index(this) === 1);
    $("#select1Works").val("").trigger("change");
    if ($('#select1Works').is(':visible') || $('#select2Works').is(':visible')) {
      $('#notWorkingOne').show();
    }
  })
});
```

Why is the "myBrokenDropdown" not showing?
Thank you very much

Comment: `Also, in jquery I can hide/Show the two dropdowns with the following code:` what do you mean? Are you **hiding** them or you **can** hide them but you don't..

Comment: you are missing '#' for many selectors

Comment: fixed the selectors. I need to hide/show them depending on what I clicked in a radio button, in another section of the page. The issue is that the first dropdown is showing hidden and there is no way I can show it

Comment: No, you didn't fix all selectors.

Comment: @Marc now I did

Comment: They all show up for me. I notice you haven't bothered to show your add'l HTML either, so we can't really reproduce your problem.  Why not create an example that demonstrates your issue so viewers can troubleshoot it?

Comment: they show up to me too if I'm using different online compilers using this exact code. I just included a bootstrap4 library, can that be the issue?

Comment: There's plenty about your code that's hard to follow. You need to make an example-- using JSFiddle or the code runner built into Stack Overflow-- and let people work with it. You also need to pay attention to what your browser console is telling you. It would also help if you described the behavior you want.

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue with a selector in my actual code, I missed a '#'.